# How to play over add 11, 9 etc chords

Tags: jazz, improvisation, bass-guitar

How do u approach improvising. Over extended chords like c 11 chords eg. I ask because I struggle soloing over them on jazz tunes

Comment: Does the **bass-guitar** tag mean you want to play bass guitar solos against these extended chords?

Comment: You may be having trouble with C11 because it probably isn't an 'extended' chord, it's a sloppy way of saying C7sus4 or Bb/C.

Comment: @Laurence, I wonder whether the questioner really means C11, or, rather, C#11, which would be a more typical thing... ?  (Certainly sus4 would be better if it's really C11...)

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean C11 or Cadd11 or any extended chord and also the context, so the tune, the progression. Then you will surely get more useful answers

Answer (score 2):

An obvious ploy is to incorporate the added tones into your solos. Whether on bas, or any other instrument. You can enclose those tones, by playing a semitone above and/or below prior, but it's *where* and *how* you fit in chord tones in any case that define good lines in soloing. But again, that may depend on the sort of jazz you're playing. Without a more explicit question, there won't be a more explicit answer!

Answer (score 2):

Do you think in a 'chord = scale' sort of way? What scale would you play for a C major chord?   C, E, G then the other notes will probably come from the diatonic scale of the prevailing key or mode (that's how it works, doesn't it?)  But if there are chord extensions, perhaps ♭9 or ♯11, it tells you your scale will include THOSE notes.

(However, as I mentioned in a previous comment, beware of 'C11'.  It SHOULD mean C, E, G, B♭, D, F.  But it very often doesn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to look at them:

- Disregard the chords and play pentatonic licks on the key center. This practically always works and sounds bluesy. The only thing you need to be able to do is, keep track of where the center is.
- If the upper structure notes are diatonic, and no sharp/flat extensions, you don't necessarily have to care about them. Play over a C9 or C13 like you would play over a C7. It's a dominant chord, that's all. Play whatever you would play over any dominant seventh chord. Try altered or diminished scale notes.
- Utilize the extension notes and emphasize them. In a C9, there's a G minor triad up there.
- Keep in mind that a written "11" chord very often means "7sus4" like Laurence says. Even though in a theoretical eleventh chord there should be a third, in practice you don't play the third there. Or play the upper structure triad. Very often, a "G11" means "F/G", and you could play an F major triad to outline the chord if there's a bassist.
- If the written extension notes have sharps or flats, they may be important for the arrangement's intended feel. Like if there's a sharp eleventh, you could try to hit that at some point in your solo.
- Pay attention to the seventh - is it a minor i.e. dominant, or a major seventh? This is very important. If the tune calls for a dominant seventh, playing a major seventh sounds really bad and ruins the progression.
- Listen to the tune as a whole and reduce it in your mind to basic tonic/subdominant/dominant roles. There's a written "13" chord, but what is it really doing? Is it just a fancy major chord, or are the extension notes actually needed?
- For the advanced and adventurous player, disregard the chords altogether, imagine your own chords in a different key and go "outside". Though IMO you should then be able to come back and land back on a sensible "inside" note at some point. :)
- Play the tune's melody! It should go together with the chords.